# Is the handler suppose to populate content-type in http response header?

Tags: http, go

Below handler handles `GET` request, without populating http `Response` header:

```
// ListAll handles GET requests and returns all current products
func (p *ProductHandler) ListAll(rw http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    p.l.Println("[DEBUG] get all records")

    prods := data.GetProducts()

    err := data.ToJSON(prods, rw)
    if err != nil {
        // we should never be here but log the error just incase
        p.l.Println("[ERROR] serializing product", err)
    }
}
```

---

Below handler handles `GET` request, populating http `Response` header:

```
// ListAll handles GET requests and returns all current products
func (p *ProductHandler) ListAll(rw http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    p.l.Println("[DEBUG] get all records")

    rw.Header().Add("Content-Type", "application/json")

    prods := data.GetProducts()

    err := data.ToJSON(prods, rw)
    if err != nil {
        // we should never be here but log the error just incase
        p.l.Println("[ERROR] serializing product", err)
    }
}
```

---

Both cases are working fine with simple curl request.

For any http client,

When do we need to populate `content-type` header, before sending the response, to client?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Always read the documentation first!

The answer to this is clearly covered [here](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ResponseWriter) (emphasis obviously added):

> // If WriteHeader has not yet been called, Write calls
> // WriteHeader(http.StatusOK) before writing the data. **If the Header
>
> // does not contain a Content-Type line, Write adds a Content-Type set
>
> // to the result of passing the initial 512 bytes of written data to
>
> // DetectContentType.** Additionally, if the total size of all written
> // data is under a few KB and there are no Flush calls, the
> // Content-Length header is added automatically.

To explicitly answer your secondary question:

> When do we need to populate `content-type` header?

Any time you don't want it to be automatically detected. Automatic detection is imprecise, so you generally don't want to rely on it.

Comment: The added point of *"Automatic detection is imprecise"* is an important one. Other points might be that the response is created in chunks so automatic detection might not even work since not enough data are available yet. And maybe one might want to simply skip the overhead of using DetectContentType if the type is clear.